# Jquery/JSON get or load?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i need to be able to create a carousel slide show on my main index.html using JSON.

1. I am very green to jquery.
2. I have NEVER used JSON, so this will be a learning experience.

Our back end developer has created a JSON url for me at example.com/property/slideshow_json

which outputs the following array -

```
[{"price": "200,000", "mls_number": "5020260", "address": "26688 Amberwood, PERRYSBURG 43551"}, {"price": "200,000", "mls_number": "5046893", "address": "29146 Lime City, PERRYSBURG 43551"}, {"price": "204,900", "mls_number": "5039812", "address": "5357 Fredelia, TOLEDO 43623"}]
```

the image url would be the `src="/property/photo/<!-- "mls_number" -->/1"`
and the content within the carousel caption would look something like this -

```
<h4><!-- "address" --></h4>
<p><!-- "price" --></p>
```

Ok so please someone help me pull this off :)

Comment: i made easy example here http://jsfiddle.net/HcV4V/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/property/slideshow_json").done(function(data){
//data is the array you expected.
showCarousel(data, 0);
})

function showCarousel(arr, index){
if(index >= arr.length) index = 0;

var item = arr[index];
//update the dom using the data item.mls_number, item.address, item.price

//set the timer
setTimeout(function(){
showCarousel(arr, index+1);
}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I used this script and it works great except that i also need to get the key # for this

$(".carousel-indicators").append($('<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' +index.key+ '"</li>'));

What would I need to add?

Comment: and the images are not loading until i use one of the indicator arrows from the carousel script

Comment: what's the key here? index is a number is that the key? can you put it in a jsfiddle? it would be easier that way.

Comment: this is a fiddle i had worked up before we went the JSON route, but will give you an idea http://jsfiddle.net/AS9tz/8/

nevermind...you are 100% correct i can use index as my number (FACEPALM MOMENT)

Comment: ok only one last issue, the slides are not loading initially and have to be triggers for the slideshow to start, see http://sandbox.dev.activemls.com any ideas?

Comment: solved i was calling $('.carousel').carousel({interval: 3000}) in the wrong place